# How to map ID column from @SecondaryTable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-annotations

I have an entity like this, and I am failing on mapping the **ID** column of the second_table to **chId** of my entity, but in the case of **dep_id** mapping works fine

Stacktrace is:

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.example.entity.ClientData column: id
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "first_table")
@SecondaryTable(name = "second_table")
public class ClientData {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    private String id;

    // Id from 2nd table
    @Column(name = "id", table = "second_table")
    private String chId; 

    @Column(name = "dep_id", table = "first_table")
    private String depId;

    @Column(name = "dep_id", table = "second_table")
    private String chDepId;
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Define fail exactly?  As per the javadoc, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/persistence/javadoc-1_0-fr/javax/persistence/SecondaryTable.html the 'id' column in the second table is defaulted to be a FK to the first table, so there is no need for a 'chId' property; it must always be identical to the 'id' property.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `insertable = false, updatable = false` solved the problem, **ID** from other tables mapped exactly as I wanted